# Как лучше проиндексировать таблицу MySQL?

Tags: mysql, индексы

Имеется множество запросов к базе следующего вида:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `ip` = '000.000.000.000' ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC
```

Вопрос: Правильно будет проиндексировать столбцы `ip` и `updated_at` вместе или только столбец `ip`? Индексы какого типа необходимо использовать?

В таблице > 6 миллионов строк, не затормозит ли работу индексация, если я прямо сейчас сделаю запрос на создание индекса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексация наоборот улучшает оптимизацию. В данном случае Вам нужно сделать составной индекс ip и updated_at `CREATE INDEX ip_updated ON users(ip, updated_at);`

Ваш же случай описан [здесь](https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B2+MySQL)

> Сортировка
>
> Составные индексы также можно использовать, если выполняется
>   сортировка:
>
> SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender = 'male' ORDER BY age В этом случае
>   нам нужно будет создать индекс в другом порядке, т.к. сортировка
>   (ORDER) происходит после фильтрации (WHERE):
>
> CREATE INDEX gender_age ON users(gender, age); Такой порядок колонок в
>   индексе позволит выполнить фильтрацию по первой части индекса, а затем
>   отсортировать результат по второй.

Comment: Спасибо, я про "не затормозит ли работу" имею в виду если я сейчас запрос выполню, а туда пишутся активно новые строки, все ок будет?)

Comment: @ВладимирСоловьев Любой индекс несколько замедляет вставку новых данных, так как может требоваться перестройка части индекса. Но если вы не делаете на таблице десятки разных индексов, то разница будет не особо заметна. Хотя если вы каждый день вставляете по миллиону строк, то любой дополнительный индекс это уже довольно серьезно

Comment: @ВладимирСоловьев По идее впишутся, в любом случае Вы можете использовать запросы EXPLAIN и прочее, чтобы оценить "эффективность" индексов. Оптимизация и индексация - это вещь регулярная, а не "сделал и забыл"

Comment: @Peresada Спасибо. Проиндексировалось. Минуты 1,5 БД правда не отвечала. Я уж испугался) посмотрим как будет в итоге

Comment: А если Вы ещё и тип поля для IP измените с текстового на числовой (INET_ATON/INET_NTOA в помощь) - получите дополнительное ускорение (и таблицы станут компактнее...).